# c# How to check if a string is a substring of an element in an array, and then print that out?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, console

Ok, so to make it more understandable, here is a code snippet:

```
string text1 = "Just a test.";
string text2 = "Another test.";
Console.Write("Search here: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

if (text1.Contains(userInput))
{
   Console.WriteLine(text1);
} 
else if (text2.Contains(userInput))
{ 
   Console.WriteLine(text2);
} 
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No match.");
}
```

Now, my problem is the following: I want to have lots of these text1 text2 strings, and I don't want to write 100 lines of if statements.
 So I thought, I should put them in an array. However, I simply can't write any kind of code that would do what I want:

- Find if any element in the array contains the userInput as a substring //array.Any?//, and then print out those elements in their entirety.

I want to print out every element that has it as a substring, so if userInput is = "test" it should print out both text1 and text2, but if it is "Another" it should only print out test2.

Do you think this is possible, and if so, what kind of container should I use because arrays seems to be too... well, not dynamic to use for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this. Use [`List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead of an array. Then you can use Linq's [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where) to filter the list down to only the matching ones.

```
var strings = new List<string> { "Just a test.", "Another test." };

Console.Write("Search here: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

var matching = strings.Where(s => s.Contains(userInput)).ToList();
if (matching.Count == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("No match.");
} else {
    foreach (var match in matching) {
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }
}
```

Note that [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/system.string.contains) is case-sensitive by default. If you want it to be case-insensitive, you can use `s.IndexOf(userInput, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > -1`

Comment: You can use Linq on arrays.  Also since they use `if-else if` it would seem that `FirstOrDefault` would make more sense.

Comment: In fact, you can use LINQ on any collection that implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @juharr Notice that he has just as many `if` statements as there are strings to compare to. He seems to want to compare to all of them, not just find the first. In fact, he says so in the body of the question.

Comment: @JuhaszGamingChannel No problem. I added an example at the end to make the comparison case-insensitive if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `for loop` with `list` is the most basic solution.

Something like this:

```
List<string> texts = new List<string>(); // a list that holds all your strings
texts.Add("Just a test.");
texts.Add("Another test.");

Console.WriteLine("Search Here");
int num_matched = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < texts.Count; i++) {
    if (texts[i].Contains(userInput)) {
        Console.WriteLine("texts[i]");
        num_matched++;
    }
}
if (num_matched == 0) {
    Console.WriteLine("No match");
}
```

Comment: The use of `if-else if` means that it should stop on the first match.

Comment: I think you might want to remove the quotes on this line: `Console.WriteLine("texts[i]");`

Answer (score 0):

An array would be fine as a storage mechanism to store the strings to be searched. You should probably specify whether you need to be case sensitive or not, because that could change your results.

You can use `LINQ` to accomplish what you want:

```
var possibleStrings = new string[] { "This is a test", "Another test" };
Console.WriteLine("Enter input: ");
var userInput = Console.ReadLine();
foreach (var match in possibleStrings.Where(ps => ps.Contains(userInput))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the `IndexOf` method, which allows you to do a case-insensitive comparison. This way the user wouldn't have to know that "Another" has to be capitalized.

And yes, storing your items in a `List<string>` will be easier to work with than an array.

Here's an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var bookTitles = new List<string>
    {
        "The Catcher in the Rye",
        "Pride and Prejudice",
        "The Great Gatsby",
        "Alice's Adventures in Wonderland",
        "Moby Dick",
        "Gulliver's Travels",
        "Hamlet",
        "The Canterbury Tales",
        "Catch-22",
        "The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn"
    };

    bool tryAgain = true;

    while (tryAgain)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a search term: ");
        string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

        var results = bookTitles.Where(title =>
            title.IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);

        if (results.Any())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nResults:");
            Console.WriteLine(" - " + string.Join("\n - ", results));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("\nNo matches found.");
            Console.ResetColor();
        }

        Console.Write("\nTry again? (y/n): ");
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.N) tryAgain = false;
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }

    Console.Write("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]